# Beamer: display a different picture on each section title slide

Tags: beamer, templates

I would like to display a different picture on each section slide.
In my template I defined the section as follows:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytemplate}[1][default-section.png]
{
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0.32cm,0.34cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth]{section page header}
      \usebeamerfont{section name}\insertsection%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0cm,0.2\paperheight)
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img/#1}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.8cm}(0.94\paperwidth,0.82\paperheight)
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{img/logo.png}
  \end{textblock*}
}
```

Then in my presentation I do:

```
% Automatic section frame
\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage{}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}[intro.png]
```

The section page is displayed, but the image in it is always the `default-section.png` from the template, the parameter is not passed through.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to invoke `\setbeamertemplate` before each section?

Comment: May it be a problem that it is section page instead of sectionpage?

Comment: Maybe, however apart from the image in the parameter not changing, the template works of, I get section slides rendered correctly.

Comment: Hello, could you provide us with a minimal working example, so that we do not have to rebuild your style from scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument you define is for the section page template, not for the `\section` macro. You can switch to different images by calling `\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytemplate][example-image-duck]` in your presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{textpos}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytemplate}[1][example-image]
{
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0.32cm,0.34cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth]{section page header}
      \usebeamerfont{section name}\insertsection%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vfill
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0cm,0.2\paperheight)
    \includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth]{#1}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.8cm}(0.94\paperwidth,0.82\paperheight)
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
  \end{textblock*}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytemplate]

    
% Automatic section frame
\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytemplate][example-image-duck]
\section{Introduction}
\endgroup

\section{Introduction}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: So `[example-image]` in decinition `\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytemplate}[1][example-image]` is the optional argument that can be replaced with `[example-image-duck]` in the function call `\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytemplate][example-image-duck]`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `example-image` is the default value which will be used if no second optional argument is given in `\setbeamertemplate`

Comment: Thanks, great answer for a relevant use case!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You're welcome!